How to deserialize polymophic JSON, when type is in out wrapper class?
I have two JSON to deserialize like this:
 { "type": "cat", "animal": { "color": "red", "canJump": true }}
 { "animal": { "color": "red", "canFly": true }, "type": "bird" }

The example in the docs, type field are always in the animal JSON element.
Data classes
data class Wrapper(val type: AnimalType, val animal: IAnimal)
data class Bird(val color: String, val canFly: Boolean): IAnimal
data class Cat(val color: String, val canJump: Boolean): IAnimal

I tried to write a customer serializer to handle it.
animalType = input.decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, index, AnimalType.serializer())
animal = input.decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, index, when(animalType) {
                    AnimalType.CAT -> ...
                    AnimalType.BIRD -> ...
                })

Because type is not always before animal, when the program tries read the value of animalType, an error will occur.
I don't have an idea to handle deserialization for this situation right now. Custom serialization or any other method in ktx-serialization are both OK.

I suggest having a polymorphic wrapper class.
@Serializable
sealed class Wrapper {
    abstract val animal: Animal
}

@Serializable @SerialName("bird")
data class BirdWrapper(override val animal: Bird) : Wrapper()
@Serializable @SerialName("cat")
data class CatWrapper(override val animal: Cat) : Wrapper()

@Serializable
sealed class Animal {
    abstract val color: String
}

@Serializable
data class Bird(override val color: String, val canFly: Boolean) : Animal()
@Serializable
data class Cat(override val color: String, val canJump: Boolean) : Animal()


fun main() {
    val testList = """
            [{ "type": "cat", "animal": { "color": "red", "canJump": true }},
            { "animal": { "color": "red", "canFly": true }, "type": "bird" }]
        """.trimIndent()
    println(Json.decodeFromString<List<Wrapper>>(testList))
}

// Outputs [CatWrapper(animal=Cat(color=red, canJump=true)), BirdWrapper(animal=Bird(color=red, canFly=true))]


I use jsonDecoder directly at last. In your way, I need to both create new wrapper an d new animal when a new Animal appears.I feel kotlinx serialization not support well for this.
